# Why I can't use two threads holding the same socket in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Here is the code:

```
TaskA a = new TaskA(this.serverSocket, this.socket);
a.assignConfig(this.config);
this.threada = new Thread(a);
this.threada.start();

TaskB b = new TaskB(this.serverSocket, this.socket);
b.assignConfig(this.config);
this.threadb = new Thread(b);
this.threadb.start();
```

In TaskA, this class work like that:

```
        if (this.serversocket == null) {
            this.serversocket = new ServerSocket(this.config.getI_respondPort());
        }

        if (this.serversocket != null) {
            System.out
                    .println("this.serversocket " + this.serversocket);
        }

        this.serversocket.setSoTimeout((int) this.config
                .getL_respondSocketInterval());

        while (this.is_keepRun()) {
                System.out.println("Keep Listening");

                Thread.sleep(this.config.getL_heartBeatInterval());
        }
```

And the TaskB is like this:

```
    while (this.is_keepRun()) {

            if (this.serversocket != null) {
                System.out.println("waiting input");

                this.socket = this.serversocket.accept();

                System.out.println("Connection received from "
                        + this.socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            }

    }
```

I assign the same serverSocket and socket via their own constructor, but when the socket got the connection, TaskA can do the `serversocket.accept`, but the TaskB's serversocket is always null, wt did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ServerSockets are looking for new socket connections, and block on a given port. If you want multiple server sockets use multiple ports. If you want multiple threads on various sockets, then use one server socket, and have a thread to do the work once its created. The accept is just waiting for one to be created, see here for a good basic intro to sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html